# apt is slow all of a sudden on debian

Tags: debian, apt

I am using debian 8 jessie.

Just a few days ago, it seems like, all of my apt updates are slow, and packages are seemingly impossible to install. They just hang when connecting to the servers.

One thing I noticed is that all of the addresses are ipv6, which is definitely not what it used to be.

When I run `sudo apt-get update`, it works, but it takes 5 minutes, when it's usually like 15 seconds.

When I try to get a package, it hangs. For example, I am trying to install `sane` for my printer:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 sane
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 79 not upgraded.
Need to get 118 kB of archives.
After this operation, 291 kB of additional disk space will be used.
0% [Connecting to http.us.debian.org (2610:148:1f10:3::89)]
```

And it just kinda stays like that. It does complete at some point. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I simply disable ipv6 system wide and it fixes this issue (and a few others with some packages related to scanning mail for spam/viruses, etc)

Comment: @ivanivan because ipv6 is going to be important soon, at least I think, I only disabled it with apt.

Comment: remarkably this and related ipv6 issues remain a problem in 2021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be internet slow issue:

```
0% [Connecting to http.us.debian.org (2610:148:1f10:3::89)]
```

It resolved an IPv6 address for `http.us.debian.org`, assume IPv6 is not very popular in the world, can you use IPv4 in `/etc/hosts` and re-run `apt` again?

Comment: I can try that.

Comment: It would also be nice to explain how to do that.

Comment: #ping http.us.debian.org you should get the IP for example, mine is 208.80.154.15 # edit /etc/hosts file http.us.debian.org 208.80.154.15

Comment: Thats not the best way, as there are many different servers apt goes through. Instead, I disabled apt to use ipv6 at all.